# Show/Hide status bar should not effect activity state

Tags: android, statusbar

I am using a webview to in an activity to load an ebook. Now when I set an event to show/hide status bar, it resizes the webview.

While hiding the  status bar, it pushes an activity up and while showing the status bar, it pushes down the activity layout.

How can I prevent this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN) to set your activity layout to use the same screen area on Android 4.0 and Lower that's available when you've enabled [FLAG_FULLSCREEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_FULLSCREEN). This prevents your content from resizing when the status bar hides and shows.

On Android 4.1 and higher, you can set your application's content to appear behind the status bar, so that the content doesn't resize as the status bar hides and shows. To do this, use [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN).

see [Hiding the Status Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html) for more info and see [Responding to UI Visibility Changes](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html)

Comment: but am using action bar also, so if I will use this flag then it will hide action bar behind status bar

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, refer the below code:

```
private void setNavVisibility(boolean visible) {

    int newVis = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
    //In case of visibility false, hide status bar, action bar and bottom layout
    if (!visible) {
        newVis |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        relativeLayoutBottom.startAnimation(fadeOut);
    }
    else
        relativeLayoutBottom.startAnimation(fadeIn);
    rootView.setSystemUiVisibility(newVis);
}
```

and on click event, call

```
   int curVis = rootView.getSystemUiVisibility();

   setNavVisibility((curVis&View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE) != 0);
```